# Generate a method via Xamarin Studio Shortcut

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I was using Visual studio and once you double tap it, it generates the corresponding method for you automatically.

However, recently I have started using Mac operating system and Xamarin Studio and would like to know whether or not there is a same shortcut to generate same functionality.

```
myListView.ItemClick += mListView_Click;
```

The following method created automatically in Visual Studio when you double tapped. But I do not know in Xamarin Studio.

```
void mListView_Click(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine ("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on source code analysis for this to be enabled (within the preferences section of Xamarin Studio):

[image]

Restart Xamarin Studio for this to take effect. You should now be able to auto-generate event handlers like in Visual Studio:

[image]

Alternatively, write out the method name in full, right click, select *Fix* then *Create Method*: 
[image]

Comment: I believe static analysis must be turned __on__ in preferences for this to work

Comment: if you have a second matthewrobbinsdev, i noticed you're on OSX Yosemite with those screenshots; how do you like it? I'm still one behind, and I plan to upgrade before El Capitan comes out. Does it work well for you?

Comment: Yeah its great. The new UI paradigms didn't impress me when I first saw them (removal of expand button in top right in favour of the green expand button etc) but I grew to like it. Spotlight is a bit different but once you learn to press down to view more results its fine. To be honest, I use terminal for a lot of my system navigation so I didn't notice a huge leap of improvement (but there is still a leap).

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Studio, just click on the method name you have written `mListView_Click` and type `Alt + Return`. This shall provide you a pop-up to generate the method, and also a small view of how it shall look, select the same. Please refer the image below.

[image: Generate method in Xamarin Studio]